For loop within kubectl exec
I want to understand how we could run a for loop or complex commands inside kubectl exec. Currently I'm running the following and getting an error.
kubectl exec -it my-statefulset-0 -n my-namespace -- for i in {0..5}; do curl http://my-statefulset-$i.svc:8080/health; done

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'


From the docs:

Use kubectl exec to execute commands directly.

kubectl exec -it pod-name -- /bin/bash -c "command(s)"

The for loop is not a command, try to use this:
[...] -- /bin/bash -c "for i in {0..5}; do curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/health; done"

or
[...] -- sh -c "for i in {0..5}; do curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/health; done"

